# Selenium webdriver не может найти элемент

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Пытаюсь с помощью селениума автоматизировать изменение цен товаров в каталоге на Tilda. Чтобы найти окно с вводом цены использовал поиск By.Xpath, css_selector и т.д., но везде одна и та же ошибка:

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="product869008511941"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[6]/div/div[2]/input"}

Ниже прилагаю исходный код и часть моего кода с поиском элемента на Python[image: Исходный код]

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
input_tab = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="product869008511941"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[6]/div/div[2]/input')
input_tab.send_keys(7800)
```

Comment: Вы используете Python?

Comment: Да, в Jupyter notebook